QR Code Error Correction vs Size
I have X square centimetres of available space on my poster/sticker/etc.
I could generate a smaller QR code (larger pixels) if I select a lower error correction level, or vice versa.
Are larger pixels less likely to be mis-scanned by a phone camera or are smaller pixels that will be mis-scanned but corrected by the additional error correction information better?

This will probably depend on the quality of print and the capabilities of the camera as well, and I would guess that there are discussions online regarding this very topic. The thing is, this topic is off topic on this site, as it is not about computer hardware or software as you have presented it. That doesn't make it a bad question, just that this site is not where it should be asked.

@music2myear That's fair, I was hoping someone would be able to say approximately, for most real-world use, what pixel sizes and error levels work best.
I was unable to find anything like that, only explanations of what the error encoding is. I would disagree that this is the incorrect site, it has the most QR code-related questions of any StackExchange site.
